# JEST AND BABEL 7

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs, nodemon, babel-jest

I am using typeorm and I have created a test file (city.test.js) inside a entity folder src/entity/City/citi.test.js The test runs without problems when doing npm run test (which just runs jest), the problem is when I want to start the service so I can work with it.

My command is:

```
"serve": "nodemon ./src/index.js --ext js,graphql --ignore 'src/**/*.test.js' --exec babel-node"
```

but I get this result

```
Error: ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

And I suppose is my test file, it is not getting ignore, any idea what should I do. ?

Thank you.